# Powershell Group files by name

Tags: powershell

I need to group files by same name,

Can you please give -me some help on this?

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\ -File
```

Result:

```
      Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                          
      ----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                          
      -a----        05/14/2021     22:41        7969726 el arte_12.mp4                                                                                                
      -a----        05/14/2021     22:41        8362639 el arte_17.mp4                                                                                                
      -a----        05/14/2021     22:41       11643387 la mÃºsica_15.mp4                                                                                             
      -a----        05/14/2021     22:41       10493118 la mÃºsica_4.mp4                                                                                             
      -a----        05/14/2021     22:41       10785013 la vida de antes_10.mp4                                                                                       
      -a----        05/14/2021     22:41       17414318 la vida de antes_16.mp4                                                                                                                                                                            
      -a----        05/14/2021     22:41       11555623 los animales_14.mp4                                                                                           
      -a----        05/14/2021     22:41       11065325 los animales_3.mp4                                                                                            
      -a----        05/14/2021     22:41       16769290 los juegos_1.mp4                                                                                              
      -a----        05/14/2021     22:41       11042762 los juegos_11.mp4                                                                                                                                                                                         
      -a----        05/14/2021     22:41       10721211 _13.mp4
```

How can i group files by th same name ? This names are different by diretory

I`ve this variable with the names values

$AllTopics

```
Count Name                     
----- ----                     
4 los juegos               
4 el arte                  
2 los animales             
3 la mÃºsica               
3 la vida de antes         
1
```

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: `Get-Help Group-Object -Full`

Comment: What do you mean by ***"This names are different by diretory"***? In addition, to group the files by a custom condition we to know which condition we can use, i.e. I can see all the files there have an ***\_*** we could use that to split and select the left side to compare the names, but, will all files have **\_** ? You need to be more specific.

Comment: @Santiago, thanks for your answer, this names are just an example, it could be another names. This names could be any names.

Comment: As I said before, without a known condition to compare the names we can't help you.

Comment: example: el arte has 2 files, the idea is group those files by name "el arte", and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Group-Object` accepts a calculated property expression in place of a property name, meaning we can do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -File |Group-Object { $_.Name -replace '_.*$' } -NoElement
```

`Group-Object` will then calculate the value of `$_.Name -replace '_.*'` for each file and group them accordingly, and output groups like below:

```
Count Name
----- ----
    2 el arte
    2 la mÃºsica
    2 la vida de antes
    2 los animales
    2 los juegos
    1
```

Comment: This works considering the file names will have an underscore as the names displayed in the question and everything in the left side of it is what matches, probably I expressed myself wrongly in my comment...

Comment: oh man ya beat me to it. In regards to @Santiagos comment, I guess the `.SubString()` method could be used instead? `$_.Name.Substring(0,4)`.

Comment: @Mathias, thanks a lot, once again! How can i get the Fullname of each one?

Comment: What do you mean full name? As in the path? The name with the extension?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, the path, export each different group to a txt file

Comment: @Paulo remove the `-NoElement` switch and `Group-Object` will output a `Group` property that has all the original grouped items

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, yes i already do that you suggests, i need that each group export separately. In this case we have 5 groups. Ex: el arte group has 2 files, and i need to export the path od those files for each group individually

Comment: @AbrahamZinala You'd want something closer to `$_.Name.Remove($_.Name.LastIndexOf('_'))` if you want to do it without regex

Comment: @Paulo And what's the problem? Unsure which cmdlet to use to write to a text file?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, if i export now, that appear all files fullpath, but i need that only export, the path for each group. Ex: el arte group has 2 files, and i need to export the path only those 2 files. And so on for next group

Comment: @Paulo So, `... |Group-Object ... |ForEach-Object {$_.Group.FullName | Set-Content "$($_.Name).txt" }`?

Comment: Well, this give -me this error massage.Set-Content : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its 
properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:1 char:163
+ ... FullName }| Set-Content C:\Scripts\Video_Time\Output\ "$($_.Name).txt ..

Comment: Ok, i solve that error message, but don`t export any data to txt file. The txt is empty

Comment: @Paulo Did you remember to _remove_ `-NoElement`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, thats it! Thanks a lot, you rock.